# AsyncTask doesn`t work in custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I`m create list of points of sales from SQLite using custom adapter

```
    dbHelper = new YourVoiceDatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    pointsList = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Point> pl = new ArrayList<Point>();
    PointsListArrayAdapter adapter;

    adapter =  new PointsListArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            pointsList,
            getActivity().getFilesDir(),
            getResources().getString(R.string.Local_Resorces_Folder),
            dbHelper);

    pointsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pl =  dbHelper.getAllPoints();

    if(myLocation != null) {
        for (Point el : pl) {
            elLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(el.getLatitude()));
            elLocation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(el.getLongtitude()));

            if (myLocation.distanceTo(elLocation) <= 999) {
                pointsList.add(el);
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Не удалось определить ваше местоположение, проверте ваши разрешения и настройки",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To custom adapter I send instance of my database ad using it in there and this slows my main tread. I`m trying to use AsyncTask in adapter to get images path from database and set images but Async do absolutely NOTHING

```
    package ua.com.it_artel.tvoy_golos.service;
```

public class PointsListArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
Context context;
private List<Point> pointsList;
private File appFolder;
private String resoursesFolder;
private YourVoiceDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private String imagePath;

public PointsListArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Point> pointsList, File appFolder, String resoursesFolder, YourVoiceDatabaseHelper dbHelper) {
    this.context = context;
    this.pointsList = pointsList;
    this.appFolder = appFolder;
    this.resoursesFolder = resoursesFolder;
    this.dbHelper = dbHelper;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pointsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return pointsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return pointsList.get(position).getId();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image;
    TextView adress;
    TextView name;
    TextView distance;
    Location elLocation;
    Point point;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element_layout_type_1, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.elLocation = new Location("");

        viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

        viewHolder.adress = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);

        viewHolder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

        viewHolder.distance = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_distance);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.elLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(pointsList.get(position).getLatitude()));
    viewHolder.elLocation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(pointsList.get(position).getLongtitude()));

    viewHolder.point = pointsList.get(position);
    new AdapterImageSetter().execute(viewHolder);

    viewHolder.adress.setText(pointsList.get(position).getAddress());

    viewHolder.name.setText(dbHelper.getPartnerByUID(pointsList.get(position).getPartnerUid()).getName());

    viewHolder.distance.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(MyLocationListener.myLocation.distanceTo(viewHolder.elLocation))) + " м");

    return rowView;

}

private class AdapterImageSetter extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, ViewHolder> {

    @Override
    protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];

        imagePath = dbHelper.getPointsPartnerImage(viewHolder.point.getPartnerUid());

        if (imagePath.equals("")) {
            viewHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        } else {
            Drawable dr = Drawable.createFromPath(appFolder.getPath() + "/" + resoursesFolder + "/" + imagePath);
            viewHolder.image.setImageDrawable(dr);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }
}
```

}

I have tried different variations in AsyncTask and Runnable but it doesn`t work, like if there are no code.. Hope u understand my English and someone give advice

Comment: read about `Loader`s, e.g. `CursorLoader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not perform ui related operations in doInBackground method for ui related operation just use onpostexcecute method
more about asynch task http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

in your code you you setting imege

```
if (imagePath.equals("")) {
            viewHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        } else {
            Drawable dr = Drawable.createFromPath(appFolder.getPath() + "/" + resoursesFolder + "/" + imagePath);
            viewHolder.image.setImageDrawable(dr);
        }
```

just add this code in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Also he can use runOnUIThread() to make it from doInBackground().

Comment: yes but why to do if aynchtask provide you all structure.. it will be used but here it's not required

Answer (score 0):

It`s work! I also add some code in Async, all work BUT but toooo much time is necessary for images and names appeared.

private class AdapterImageSetter extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected ViewHolder doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = params[0];

        viewHolder.imagePath = dbHelper.getPointsPartnerImage(viewHolder.point.getPartnerUid());

        viewHolder.pointName = dbHelper.getPartnerByUID(viewHolder.point.getPartnerUid()).getName();
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ViewHolder viewHolder) {

        if (viewHolder.imagePath.equals("")) {
            viewHolder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        } else {
            Drawable dr = Drawable.createFromPath(appFolder.getPath() + "/" + resoursesFolder + "/" + viewHolder.imagePath);
            viewHolder.image.setImageDrawable(dr);
        }

        viewHolder.name.setText(viewHolder.pointName);

        Log.i("IMAGE PATH", viewHolder.imagePath);
        Log.i("PARTNER UID", viewHolder.point.getPartnerUid());
    }
}
```

For more information: this list is on first screen when u open app.
In first activity I replace fragment and шт the fragment I'm doing all the operations. have any ideas how to speed up operations in AsyncTask?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: for setting and image in listview or adapter it will good you use some libraruies like picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ or something you find better one

Comment: thx a lot, great lib, but my problem in loading image path and point name from database, it eats all the time  =(